# Display JSON data from FETCH in HTML

Tags: html, json, fetch-api

I need to take the (html) section from each page in the array (0, 1) how would I go about doing this? The API call worked perfectly fine, just need to take the main html data and display it on the web page where the placeholders `{welcome.text}` and `{about.text}` are.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CMS Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <header>
            <h1>CMS Test</h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="#Home">Home</a>
                <a href="#About">About</a>
                <a href="#Posts">Posts</a>
                <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
            </nav>
       </header>
       <section id="Home">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Welcome to website</h2>
                {welcome.text}
            </div>
       </section>
       <section id="About">
           <div class="container">
               <h2>About Section</h2>
               {about.text}
           </div>
       </section>
       <section id="Posts">
           <div class="container">
               <h2>Posts Section</h2>
               {posts.list}
           </div>
       </section>
       <section id="Contact">
           <div class="container">
               <h2>Contact Section</h2>
               <p>contact on: email@provider.com</p>
           </div>
       </section>
<script>
    fetch('http://68.183.219.114/ghost/api/v3/content/pages/?key=276f4fc58131dfcf7a268514e5')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

JSON response after fetching from that URL.

```json
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "id": "5efb6bbeeab44526aecc0abb",
      "uuid": "38b78123-e5a8-4346-8f6e-6f57a1a284d0",
      "title": "About Section",
      "slug": "about-section",
      "html": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
      "comment_id": "5efb6bbeeab44526aecc0abb",
      "feature_image": null,
      "featured": false,
      "visibility": "public",
      "created_at": "2020-06-30T16:43:42.000+00:00",
      "updated_at": "2020-06-30T16:58:53.000+00:00",
      "published_at": "2020-06-30T16:58:37.000+00:00",
      "custom_excerpt": null,
      "codeinjection_head": null,
      "codeinjection_foot": null,
      "custom_template": null,
      "canonical_url": null,
      "url": "http://68.183.219.114/about-section/",
      "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\nincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis\nnostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu\nfugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in\nculpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "reading_time": 0,
      "page": true,
      "og_image": null,
      "og_title": null,
      "og_description": null,
      "twitter_image": null,
      "twitter_title": null,
      "twitter_description": null,
      "meta_title": null,
      "meta_description": null
    },
    {
      "id": "5efb6f53eab44526aecc0ac4",
      "uuid": "26463d5f-011e-46b3-a1e2-60e213e33f6f",
      "title": "Welcome",
      "slug": "welcome",
      "html": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>",
      "comment_id": "5efb6f53eab44526aecc0ac4",
      "feature_image": null,
      "featured": false,
      "visibility": "public",
      "created_at": "2020-06-30T16:58:59.000+00:00",
      "updated_at": "2020-06-30T16:59:02.000+00:00",
      "published_at": "2020-06-30T16:59:02.000+00:00",
      "custom_excerpt": null,
      "codeinjection_head": null,
      "codeinjection_foot": null,
      "custom_template": null,
      "canonical_url": null,
      "url": "http://68.183.219.114/welcome/",
      "excerpt": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor\nincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis\nnostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\nDuis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu\nfugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in\nculpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
      "reading_time": 0,
      "page": true,
      "og_image": null,
      "og_title": null,
      "og_description": null,
      "twitter_image": null,
      "twitter_title": null,
      "twitter_description": null,
      "meta_title": null,
      "meta_description": null
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "pagination": {
      "page": 1,
      "limit": 15,
      "pages": 1,
      "total": 2,
      "next": null,
      "prev": null
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the {[identifier]} with a span or a container tag element and assign an unique id to it (in the example I am using a span tag).

When the DOM is loaded create a variable for each container tag identified by the id (or query selector, you have many possibilities).

When the fetch operation succeded (I am using a test REST endpoint), extract the data and "populate" the container tag (assigned before) with the fetched data.

Here is a working example:

```js
// FAKE DATA
const FAKE_DATA = JSON.parse(`{"pages":[{"id":"5efb6bbeeab44526aecc0abb","uuid":"38b78123-e5a8-4346-8f6e-6f57a1a284d0","title":"About Section","slug":"about-section","html":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>","comment_id":"5efb6bbeeab44526aecc0abb","feature_image":null,"featured":false,"visibility":"public","created_at":"2020-06-30T16:43:42.000+00:00","updated_at":"2020-06-30T16:58:53.000+00:00","published_at":"2020-06-30T16:58:37.000+00:00","custom_excerpt":null,"codeinjection_head":null,"custom_template":null,"canonical_url":null,"url":"http://68.183.219.114/about-section/","excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quisnostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eufugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt inculpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.","reading_time":0,"page":true,"og_image":null,"og_title":null,"og_description":null,"twitter_image":null,"twitter_title":null,"twitter_description":null,"meta_title":null,"meta_description":null},{"id":"5efb6f53eab44526aecc0ac4","uuid":"26463d5f-011e-46b3-a1e2-60e213e33f6f","title":"Welcome","slug":"welcome","html":"<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>","comment_id":"5efb6f53eab44526aecc0ac4","feature_image":null,"featured":false,"visibility":"public","created_at":"2020-06-30T16:58:59.000+00:00","updated_at":"2020-06-30T16:59:02.000+00:00","published_at":"2020-06-30T16:59:02.000+00:00","custom_excerpt":null,"codeinjection_head":null,"custom_template":null,"canonical_url":null,"url":"http://68.183.219.114/welcome/","excerpt":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod temporincididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quisnostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eufugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt inculpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.","reading_time":0,"page":true,"og_image":null,"og_title":null,"og_description":null,"twitter_image":null,"twitter_title":null,"twitter_description":null,"meta_title":null,"meta_description":null}],"meta":{"pagination":{"page":1,"limit":15,"pages":1,"total":2,"next":null,"prev":null}}}`);

// Fetch url, change with http://68.183.219.114/ghost/api/v3/content/pages/?key=276f4fc58131dfcf7a268514e5
const FETCH_URL = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2";

// Data page index 1
const PAGE_1_INDEX = 0;
// Data page index 2
const PAGE_2_INDEX = 1;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  const txtWelcome = document.getElementById("txtWelcome");
  const txtAbout = document.getElementById("txtAbout");
  const listPost = document.getElementById("listPost");

  fetch(FETCH_URL)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      // Assign page 1
      const page1 = FAKE_DATA.pages[PAGE_1_INDEX];
      // Assign page 2
      const page2 = FAKE_DATA.pages[PAGE_2_INDEX];
      
      // START populating for example with page 2
      txtWelcome.innerHTML = page2.title; // Example
      txtAbout.innerHTML = page2.slug; // Example
      listPost.innerHTML = page2.html; // Here you can add the HTML as above
      // END Populating
    });
});
```

```css
p:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CMS Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       <header>
            <h1>CMS Test</h1>
            <nav>
                <a href="#Home">Home</a>
                <a href="#About">About</a>
                <a href="#Posts">Posts</a>
                <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
            </nav>
       </header>
       <section id="Home">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Welcome to website</h2>
                <span id="txtWelcome">Loading...</span>
            </div>
       </section>
       <section id="About">
           <div class="container">
               <h2>About Section</h2>
               <span id="txtAbout">Loading...</span>
           </div>
       </section>
       <section id="Posts">
           <div class="container">
               <h2>Posts Section</h2>
               <span id="listPost">Loading...</span>
           </div>
       </section>
       <section id="Contact">
           <div class="container">
               <h2>Contact Section</h2>
               <p>contact on: email@provider.com</p>
           </div>
       </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, the data from the response is in a JSON format, and it shows an array of pages how would I select a page and then the "html" section from that page? Updated code to include JSON response.

Comment: Please provide the JSON formatted with the correct format & syntax. Can you describe better what are your trying to achieve, Thanks :)

Comment: the JSON response comes with an object, containing two other object (meta & pages) I need to access the 'html:' string from both of the items in the array

Comment: @Mac I have changed accordingly to your needs. Hope that's what are you looking for :)

Comment: @Mac I added a little bit of CSS to prove that the HTML in the JSON has been correctly represented (In this case the p tag)